# Download location of Aurora Store?

Tags: downloading

Working on an Android 6 (stock ROM) phone, which has only internal storage (no external sd card), and is not rooted.

Aurora Store is installed and updated on this phone via F-droid.

Aurora Store has a "Downloads" choice in its "hamburger" menu, where I see something like this:

[image]

So, clearly some .apk's have been downloaded - the question is, where?

I have checked the following locations:

- `/sdcard/Aurora/` - there are some random .apk's there, but not the two on the screenshot
- `/sdcard/Download/` - again, some random .apk's there, but not the two on the screenshot

With a bit of `find`, I also found the following location - but unfortunately, it turns out completely empty in `adb shell`:

```
$ ./adb shell
shell@DDDDD:/ $ ls -la /sdcard/Android/data/com.aurora.store/files/Downloads/
shell@DDDDD:/ $
```

My guess is, the .apk's Aurora downloaded are actually here - but I cannot access/see them, because I'd need root for that, and this phone is not rooted.

Could anyone confirm, what should be the default downloads directory/location for Aurora Store, on an unrooted phone with only internal storage - and whether root is needed to access these files?

Answer (score 2):

Aurora Store downloads files to app-specific storage by default (`/data/data/com.aurora.store/files/Download`).

If you want to save APKs to shared storage to access them without root, in Aurora go to **Settings** → **Downloads** and switch on "User external Storage". After this, APKs will be stored in `Android/data/com.aurora.store/files/Downloads` under Internal Storage (typically `/storage/emulated/0`).

Answer (score 0):

You are right - I had the same problem...

However, "manual download" works with this folder:

storage/emulated/0/Aurora/Store/Downloads/

...com.futuremark.pcmark.android.benchmark/

...4061/

...com.futuremark.pcmark.android.benchmark.apk

Comment: Unfortunately I do not see a directory called `Aurora` in my `/storage/emulated/0` volume.